# A merge conflicted on path (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm getting this

**A merge conflicted on path "/src/app/employee.service.ts".**

when running this command

**ng generate service employee --skipTests=true**

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 . I've searched 1 hour for solutions, but with no success

Comment: because you already have file `employee.service.ts` generated.

Comment: Does `/src/app/employee.service.ts` already exist?

Comment: @MattU it exists

Comment: Why do you want to generate it if it already exists?

Comment: @ShamPooSham I have it in the app folder, this is only error

Comment: You can't `ng generate` the service if it already exists.

Comment: @MattU thanks, I got it now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't ng generate the service because it is already existing